# macOS Help on top

Tags: macos

Some years ago I read tip to stop Help popping up on top of the open document. (At the time I found it annoying as you couldn't actually see the document.)

I would like to reverse this, but cannot remember how I did it, or even find the original hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal, simply paste the following and hit <kbd>return</kbd>:

```
defaults write com.apple.helpviewer DevMode -bool true
```

The changes should take effect immediately, though you will need to close any Help windows that are currently open.

To undo it, run the same command but with `false`:

```
defaults write com.apple.helpviewer DevMode -bool false
```